# How can we manage attendance in lms? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 40 students and each have enrolled in five courses. Every course tracks attendance: the date on which each student was present. I'm thinking to create a separate table for each student. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Hey Umer Baig, Are you just asking for what would be the best way to break up the data in to table?

Comment: What LMS are you using? Moodle? Canvas? eLearning? Angel? Blackboard?

Comment: No, I'm not asking to break up the data into the table I'm asking is there any efficient method to place and manage the attendance into the database suppose i have a student table a course table then what is the efficient method to place and manage the attendance

Answer (score 2):

You could write a stored proc that takes a comma-separated list of your student names and builds the tables from that.  However, creating 40 tables that are identical except for the name seems really inefficient.  SQL can handle large row sets, no problem.  Even if you put all of the students into the same table and they had an attendance row for all 365 days of the year (40 students x 5 courses x 365 days) is only 73,000 rows/year; that's **nothing** for SQL.

Also, if you ever wanted to do any reporting with multiple student tables, you will need to target EVERY table instead of just targeting your one main table and grouping by studentID.

In short, yes you can write a proc that will dynamically create identical tables for each student.  Is it a good (read: efficient) idea? Personally, I don't think so.  I think you could get way more performance (losing some because of larger searches but gaining some for not having to JOIN any tables) and reporting ability in a much shorter amount of time/work by keeping it all on one table.

Comment: you says that i store all the attendance of the students in one table?

Answer (score 2):

Do **NOT** create a table for each student.

What you should have is a Student table, a Course table, and an Attendance table. The Attendance table should have columns for the student key, the course key, the date, and the status (present, tardy, absent, etc).

This will be *far* more efficient than using separate tables for each student.

Comment: yeah this is efficient but for one course attendance there will be nearly 1120 rows and in this way the size of the attendance table will be so large and have many rows. is there any other efficient method to do this?

Comment: Imagine the whole university and the students which are enrolled in courses and their attendance.

Comment: @UmerBaig I'm the network admin at a college... I have a whole university where the students are enrolled in courses, and this is exactly how the attendance is stored. Believe me, it's not a problem. Databases are _good_ at this.

Comment: is there a separate table for one student attendance or is there a one table for attendance and all the attendance record is populated in this table?

Comment: There is one table for attendance and all attendance records for all students and courses live in the one table. It currently has over 52,000 records, and that's small because we rebuilt the server this year. No big deal.